# Constant Variable Re-defined?

Tags: variables, vbscript, scripting, numbers, constants

I'm using a VBScript to pick out certain parts of a .txt file based off of a pattern, and then outputting that into another .txt file. The VBScript is launched from a batch file (.BAT), and the part where the VBScript creates a .txt file named 'proceed.txt' is so that the batch file can know when the VBScript is finished, and can continue.

I keep on getting an error saying that the variable `ForWriting` on line 13 was already defined, but I don't see anywhere in the code where it was previously defined. I tried to just completely eliminate the `ForWriting` variable, and just put a 2 after the "hourextracted.txt", part, but the script for some odd reason is highly unstable that way.

The other weird thing is that the script actually works. It works fine. I keep on getting the error message, but the script still does it's job, and it does it well. All I want is for the error message to go away. I have a couple other scripts that are basically identical to this one that are used in the batch file that work perfectly fine without getting the error message, even though the code is the same. Only this one, however, gets the error message.

Here's the code:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("hour.txt", ForReading)
strSearchString = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Global = True
objRegEx.Pattern = "\d{2}"
Set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(strSearchString)  
If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
    For Each strMatch in colMatches
        Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Const ForWriting = 2
        Set obj1 = obj.OpenTextFile("hourextracted.txt", ForWriting)
        obj1.WriteLine(strMatch.Value)
        obj1.Close
        Set obj = Nothing 
        outFile = "proceed.txt"
        Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
        objFile.Write "null" & vbCrLf
        objFile.Close
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBScript the constants are replaced in the code at compile time but the declaration does not happen until the `Const` statement is reached (read [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/12/07/vbscript-constants-are-not-hoisted/)).

If you place your `Const` declaration inside a `For` loop, VBScript engine will try to declare the constant at each iteration.

So, the solution is just to place the constant declaration out of the `For` loop.

Comment: Whenever I do that, I DO stop getting the error, however, the script just seems to break. It rarely reports back an extracted number, and if it does, it's the wrong number. . . I'm not sure why. But at the same time though, that could also be a problem with my batch file.

Comment: @EthanWaldeck, without seeing your input file, knowing what the output should be, and what the batch file does it is almost impossible to determine what does not work and why. Note that your code tries to iterate over a set of matches and that the constant error makes the code only output the first match. Without the error it will output the last match.

Comment: @EthanWaldeck having the constant declared in the loop won’t fix that problem it just introduces another one. If you are more descriptive about what you are trying to accomplish and what you have tried so far instead if focusing on the constant declaration then you might get better answers. As you have focused on the constant declaration this answer has answered that.